# jQuery: How to auto scroll between sections using scroll as trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I'm trying something where users can navigate sections of a webpage without a nav bar. There are 4 sections to the page, and each section is a full screen in size (100vh). Each time the user scrolls down I want it to have an animated auto scroll to the next section.

What jQuery/javascript can I add to make this work?

html:

```
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

css:

```
section {
    background-color: #20c080;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
```

UPDATE:
jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
console.log(scroll);
if (scroll > 100 && scroll < 200) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top }, 'slow');
        return false;
}
else if ( scroll > 950 && scroll < 1050) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#work').offset().top }, 'slow');
        return false;
}
});
```

Comment: iscroll hope this will help https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your code, so I can only guess, you want to auto scroll when user scrolling their mouse right?

if that so, you can try to give every section an ID and after mouse scrolling trigger, scroll like below by JQuery

```js
var orgscroll = $(document).scrollTop(), switchcheck=false;

   function autoScroll(){
    // if(scrollable){
     if(switchcheck) return;
     switchcheck = true;

     var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
     // scrollable=false;
     
     if (scroll > orgscroll) {
      if (scroll <  $('#lalelada').offset().top) {
           $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#lalelada').offset().top }, 'slow');
      }else if ( scroll >  $('#lalelada').offset().top && scroll < $('#about').offset().top) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top }, 'slow');
      }else if ( scroll > $('#about').offset().top && scroll < $('#work').offset().top) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#work').offset().top }, 'slow');
      }else if ( scroll > $('#work').offset().top) {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#balabala').offset().top }, 'slow');
      } 
     }else if ( scroll < orgscroll) {
      alert('I\'m scroll up');
     }
     orgscroll = scroll;
    // }
    setTimeout(function(){ switchcheck = false; }, 1000)
   }

   $(window).on('scroll', autoScroll);
```

```css
section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
section:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #20c080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="work"></section>
<section id="about"></section>
<section id="lalelada"></section>
<section id="balabala"></section>
```

Comment: I find the hardest part is getting the mouse scroll event to trigger the auto scroll animation. 
I've now managed to get it to work, but it will lock onto wherever it scrolls, and I can't move it back. 
I updated the code above.

Comment: setup orgscroll for initial position and scroll for after scroll position, compare two argument, then you will know is scroll up or down

Comment: I just make a demo is it you want??

Comment: It took me a moment to get my head around how it works but I see how it works now. It's working well, and based off your example I managed to make some code to auto scroll back up too. 

Thanks heaps! 

:)